# Trouble with 32-bit two's complement hexadecimal conversion

Tags: hex

I am working on a set of problems where I need to convert **32-bit** two's complement hexadecimal values into regular decimal values. Now, my book tells me that whenever I see a hexadecimal value leading with 8 through f, it will always be negative.

The problem in question is: **0xfffffe58**

In my understanding, this means that I only start evaluating after the chain of 'f' values, leaving me with evaluating '**e58**'. 'e'will be converted into -2, '5' will stay the same, and '8' will become -8. Multiplying all the values out, i get 
(-2*16^2)+(5*16)+-8 = -512+80-8 = -440. 
Now, the answer is -424, so I am confused as to why the 8 would be positive, since the leading binary digit for 8 is 1, and we are using two's complement, it would lead me to believe that it would be -8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two's compliment it is only the most significant bit that signals that is is a negative number.  So it's only the first hexadecimal digit is 8-f that you need to check.  The less significant digits do not impact the determination.  So the 8 is not negative, it is just part of the number.

The way you are trying to do your conversion isn't correct either - you don't do a digit by digit conversion like you are trying to do, that's not how two's compliment works.

One way to do the conversion is to to a binary flip and then add one.  So F -> 0, E -> 1, etc.

So you would have `F F F F F E 5 8` -> `0 0 0 0 0 1 A 7` + `1` = `0 0 0 0 0 1 A 8` = `424`

Answer (score 1):

You're completely on the wrong track with your calculation. `e` doesn't convert to `-2`; `5` doesn't stay the same.

You need to find the matching digit so that each pair adds up to `F` (except the last which adds to `10`):

```
F F F F F E 5 8
0 0 0 0 0 1 A 8
```

The equation is that `0xFFFFFE58` + `0x000001A8` = `0x100000000` . `1A8` is `424`.